# how to test python AWS lambda function when creating zip with Additional Dependencies? localy

Tags: python, aws-lambda

i want to create python function with some additional Dependencies im using
according to this document :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html#python-package-dependencies
im need to use :
Updating a Function with Additional Dependencies section
my question how can i be sure my python script will use or if it have enough libs in the zip
in simple words how i fource my python script to use the dependesia from the the new directory im about to upload as zip ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install packages in your deployement package before uploading it to lambda.

For example your deployement package is like

lambda-package

-- lambda_function.py

-- some other files

cd into your lambda_package and install packages inside this using

```
pip install package-name -t .
```

This will install this package and -t means you are specifying target directory as your current directory

Then zip all the contents of this folder and upload it to aws lambda.

Comment: thanks but all sites say the lambda_function.py should be in the same level as the packages

Comment: how can i know which dependencies should i download and zip ?

Comment: Yes it will be at the same level when you run this pip command.

Comment: Whatever imports you are doing in your code, you should install those packages.